# Bootstrap collapse removing a href events inside of collapse div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boostrap Collapse from : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/ , but I got a problem when is a `a href` link inside my collapse.

Right now if I click in any a href inside my collapse the div collapse back, but that happen just with a href links
with text the event does not happen, someone know how can I resolve this?

In that sample when I click on **link1** my div collapse and should just
back if I click again in **link1**, what is happening now is if I click any
anchor element inside that div the div collapse back, like if I click in **link2**
or **link3**.

How can I solve this?

there is my sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/SMZHG/12/

Comment: I see that you are using bootstrap with angular and would recommend using Angular UI Bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  for bootstrap components as angular directives

Comment: thanks, but this not solve my problem.

Comment: For links inside the collapsible section stop propagation by handling onclick event and doing e.stopPropagation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In that sample when I click on **link1** my div collapse and should
>   just back if I click again in **link1**, what is happening now is if I
>   click any anchor element inside that div the div collapse back, like
>   if I click in **link2** or **link3**.

Then you must make that link1 the trigger element for collapse not the whole `li` element where both trigger anchor and collapsible div are.

Correct HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="linkClicked(2)" ng-class="{'current': activeLinks[2]}">

        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            link1<i class="pull-right fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>

        <div class="collapse collapse-styled" id="collapseExample">
            <a ng-click="linkClicked(2)" ng-class="{'current': activeLinks[2]}" href="#/session/assign">
                link 2 <i class="pull-right fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a ng-click="linkClicked(3)" ng-class="{'current': activeLinks[3]}">
                link3 <i class="pull-right fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMZHG/15/)